# Nickname / login / account name - string limitations, formatting

Tags: c#, regex

I making a simple chat application, and I need to write a claas that creates user nickname.
for example: NickName nm = NewNickname ("john123");
So, If the name is wrong (unacceptable) it should throw an exception.

Limiations:
- minimum 4 chars
- maximum 12 char (simple Length check)
- only letter and digits
- must start from letter

Now my conception is just use for loop and check every char for letter/digit etc.

But I ask, is any simple Regex (?) method to achieve this? I have no time to learn
all these regex tricks, because i have limited time (and it looks very complicated) :P

Comment: It isn't that complicated, you should really try to make one as basic as this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular Expression: "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{3,11}$"

So start with a letter (lowercase or uppercase) [a-zA-Z], then between 3 and 11 letters or numbers, so [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,11}. ^ means beginning of string, $ means end of string.

Comment: Thx, even looks simply :-) I was starting reading about char IsDigit method etc. but it looks way better than for/if statement.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Regex, it's more simple. Like that:

`private bool ValidMail(string adresse)`

{

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"^([\w]+)@([\w]+)\.([\w]+)$");

return myRegex.IsMatch(adresse);
```

}

For the Regex, you can do it yourself, juste learn about it here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: it's not what he asked.. you are validating (badly) an email here.